# Django Rest / Sum the response values of identical coins

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

from api, I get multiply records on one coin.

How can I summarize and add them to the Wallet.objects() correctly? Now I have such a code and it just overwrites the old value with a coin zero.

Example i have response

```
{"coin":"BIP","value":"5"}
{"coin":"ZERO","value":"4"}
{"coin":"BIP","value":"15"}
{"coin":"INSIDER","value":"24"}
{"coin":"BIP","value":"41"}
```

I want add in database from this response:

```
"coin":"BIP","value":"61"
"coin":"ZERO","value":"4"
"coin":"INSIDER","value":"24"
```

Its sum all BIP (5+15+41). And other coins.
How?

My Wallet.objects now cant sum this amount

```
obj, created = Wallet.objects.update_or_create(user=user, coin_id_id=coin.id, defaults={'amount_d': amount_d, 'amount_w': 0, 'cap_w': 0, 'cap_d': capitalize_d},)
    obj.save()
```

Please help. Tahanks!

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to post the actual urls you are using.  You should probably use 'example.com' instead.

Comment: update_or_create(...) will first try to update (overwrite ) a matching record and will create a new record only if there is no existing matching record found. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes..no good code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
coins = [
    {'coin': "A", 'value': 2},
    {'coin': "B", 'value': 5},
    {'coin': "A", 'value': 1},
    {'coin': "A", 'value': 3},
]

new = {}
for c in coins:
    coin_name = c.get("coin")
    coin_value = c.get("value", 0)

    new[coin_name] = new.get(coin_name, 0) + coin_value

coin = []
for key in new:
    coin.append({'coin': key, 'value': new[key]})

print(coin)
```

Result:

```
[{'coin': 'A', 'value': 6}, {'coin': 'B', 'value': 5}]
```

Edit : (bip_value added)

```
coins = [
    {'coin': "A", 'value': 2, 'bip_value': 1},
    {'coin': "B", 'value': 5, 'bip_value': 2},
    {'coin': "A", 'value': 1, 'bip_value': 3},
    {'coin': "A", 'value': 3, 'bip_value': 4},
]

new = {
    'coin': {},
    'bip': {}
}

for c in coins:
    coin_name = c.get("coin")
    coin_value = c.get("value", 0)
    bip_value = c.get("bip_value", 0)

    new['coin'][coin_name] = new['coin'].get(coin_name, 0) + coin_value
    new['bip'][coin_name] = new['bip'].get(coin_name, 0) + bip_value

coin = []
for key in new['coin']:
    coin.append({'coin': key, 'value': new['coin'][key], 'bip_value': new['bip'][key]})

print(coin)
```

Result:

```
[{'coin': 'A', 'value': 6, 'bip_value': 8}, {'coin': 'B', 'value': 5, 'bip_value': 2}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Good! So, how can 'bip_value' counting be added to this code?